# Rails Tutorial (Hartl) - Signup Confirmation extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I just finished the **Ruby on Rails** Tutorial (Michael Hartl).

At the end of the last chapter, he recommends some extensions to the sample app.  One of these extensions is `"Signup confirmation"` that he summarizes as follows:

> "Apart from an email regular expression, the sample application
>   currently has no way to verify the validity of a user’s email address.
>   Add an email address verification step to confirm a user’s signup. The
>   new feature should create users in an inactive state, email the user
>   an activation URI, and then change the user to an active state when
>   the URI gets hit. You might want to read up on state machines in Rails
>   to help you with the inactive/active transition."

Question:

Is there a common **"Rails way"** to do this?  I have done a lot of searching, but have not found a definitive solution.  Furthermore, none of the potential solutions I have found mention state machines at all.  However, since Michael Hartl mentioned it, I feel like I should consider his advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Somebody might come up with a better answer, but why not just give the User model a boolean activated field, an activation token string, send an email with an url of it to then identify by that token and activate the user. An activate member action should do it.

Of course people might say it's not REST but sometimes there are situations where it would be kinda too extensive to create an own resource.

I think on railscasts there's an episode over statemashines.

Comment: Sounds good.  But now with the boolean activated field (such as: email_confirmed), what would you suggest as the next step?  I am thinking I would use that to protect the "create" action in the Sessions controller.  Or protect the "sign_in" function in SessionsHelper.  Thoughts?